# How to make the navbar items active with Bootstrap 5

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I am building my first site with Jekyll and Bootrstap 5. I followed the instruction on the Bootstrap 5 intro page to set up my template and navbar. However, I am not able to make the items in the navbar active as I click on them.

Below you can see my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mystyle.css">
    
    <!-- Title -->
    <title>My title</title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/index"><img src="logo/logo.svg" alt="" width="" height="60">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

  
    <!-- Js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="/js/myscript.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Below is my css code (which is in the "mystyle.css" file):

```
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

And below is my js code (which is in the "myscript.js" file)

```
$(".navbar .nav-link").on("click", function(){
   $(".navbar").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to link the jquery for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did try to include the link to jQuery just before the link to JS, but it still didn't work. Anyhow, I thought that Bootrstap 5 was meant to be used without jQuery? Thanks again.

Comment: @Arianna Strange.. it did work when I tried it out. I just added a jquery CDN before the bootstrap js.

Comment: @C Y Thanks. This is weird! I added `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` before the link to the bootstrap js. I tried it also in different browsers, but nothing changed. Is there something wrong with the link I am adding? Or what else could it be? Thank again.

Comment: @Arianna Try using the inspect tool and see if there is an error in the console. Also, make sure the order is first the jquery, then bootstrap, and then your script file.